# .Net core 5.0 doesn't show up in Help Viewer 2.3

Tags: .net-core, help-viewer

My VS2019 is the latest version (16.9.0) and I have installed all .net core sdks ( up to 5.0.200) but my Help Viewer (Ver 2.3) doesn't show .net core 5. Here is an image that shows there is no .Net Core 5.

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Can you write code against .NET 5?

Comment: Yes, I can choose .NET 5.0 (currnet) in the 'Create New Project' dialog.

Comment: Where are you seeing this list? How do I show it in my VS install?

Comment: @mxmissile Well, I added a new image.